# "array subscript out of bounds" - spurious or real?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm getting a warning from GCC on the following code:

```
#include <math.h>

int init_tables() {
    int retval = 0;
    for(unsigned row = 0; row < 65536; ++row) {
        unsigned line[4] = {
                (row >>  0) & 0xf,
                (row >>  4) & 0xf,
                (row >>  8) & 0xf,
                (row >> 12) & 0xf
        };

        float monotonicity_left = 0;
        float monotonicity_right = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
            if (line[i-1] > line[i]) {
                monotonicity_left += pow(line[i-1], 4) - pow(line[i], 4);
            } else {
                monotonicity_right += pow(line[i], 4) - pow(line[i-1], 4);
            }
        }

        int i;

        for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if(line[i] == 0) {
                line[i] = line[i+1];
                break;
            } else if(line[i] == 1 && line[i+1] == 2) {
                line[i] = 3;
                break;
            } else if(line[i] == 2 && line[i+1] == 1) {
                line[i] = 3;
                break;
            } else if(line[i] == line[i+1] && line[i] >= 3) {
                if(line[i] != 15) {
                    line[i]++;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if(i == 3)
            continue;

        /* fold to the left */
        for(int j=i+1; j<3; j++)
            line[j] = line[j+1];
        line[3] = 0;

        int result = (line[0] <<  0) |
                       (line[1] <<  4) |
                       (line[2] <<  8) |
                       (line[3] << 12);

        retval += row ^ result;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Apologies for the length; this is the minimized testcase (removing almost anything, such as the `pow` or the `if` statements causes the warning to go away).

This is compiled with `g++ -O3 -Wall -c -o /dev/null test.cpp`. On both 4.8.5 and 5.3.0 (MacPorts) and 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 14.04), the result is the following warning:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int init_tables()':
test.cpp:48:31: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
             line[j] = line[j+1];
                               ^
test.cpp:48:31: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
```

As far as I can tell, the code is correct - the for loop causes `i` to take values from 0 to 3 inclusive, and the `if(i == 3)` should ensure that `j` only takes values from 1 to 2. Is this understanding correct, or is there a bug in my code?

Comment: Interesting that it's only on `-O3`, not on `-O2`.

Comment: On platforms where `unsigned` has 16 bits its maximum value is 65535, and the first loop will never end.

Comment: if "i" is "2" then line[j] = line[j+1] is equivalent to "line[3] = line[4]".  So yes, that looks like a valid warning.  But I haven't had my caffene yet, so I could be completely wrong